# New virtual creates a new method instead of hiding

Tags: c#, inheritance, moq, xunit, opc-ua

The requirement here is to write test cases for the Opc Ua NodeManager and it uses NodeId from Opc.Ua class.

Methods/properties in NodeId class cannot be moq because they are Non-Overridable methods and have ony get in them.

So I created a wrapper on top of NodeId class and tried to Moq that class. It works fine but now I have 2 methods/Properties

```
public class NodeIdTestClass : NodeId
{
    public NodeIdTestClass()
    {

    }
    public new virtual object Identifier
    {
        get => base.Identifier;
    }

    public new virtual ushort NamespaceIndex
    {
        get => base.NamespaceIndex;
    }

    public new virtual bool IsNullNodeId
    {
        get => base.IsNullNodeId;
    }
}

//Arrange

        var nodeIdMock = new Mock<NodeIdTestClass>() { CallBase = true };
        nodeIdMock.Setup(x => x.Identifier).Returns(nodeIdMock.Object.Identifier);
        nodeIdMock.Setup(x => x.NamespaceIndex).Returns(1);
        nodeIdMock.Setup(x => x.IsNullNodeId).Returns(false);
        _nodemanager.SetNamespaces(new string[] { "0", "1", "2" });

        //Act
        var result = _nodemanager.GetManagerHandle(nodeIdMock.Object);
```

The problem :

[image: Problem Object Highlighted]

Is there something wrong with code?

Comment: What's the definition of NodeId?

Comment: Even non-overridable methods can be mocked with the right framework. `new` as the name says introduces a new method to the current type, it doesn't hide existing ones accessed through the parent type.

Comment: Why do you want to mock NodeID in the first place? Assuming you refer to the OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard library, [NodeId](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/3a378e864453e58662b47e2e3c52a61966962933/Stack/Opc.Ua.Core/Types/BuiltIn/NodeId.cs) is just a value object, it has no behavior that needs mocking. No more than eg `Int31` or `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need a mock?

Wouldn't this be enough?

```
var nodeId = new NodeId(value: 17, namespaceIndex: 1);
    
var result = _nodemanager.GetManagerHandle(nodeId);
```

Comment: I am trying to test my local implementation of "protected virtual bool IsNodeIdInNamespace(NodeId nodeId)". let me see if your suggestion works,

Comment: It works!!, last time I tried "var nodeId = new NodeId(identifier: 17, namespaceIndex: 1);" Probably the reason it didn't work for me.